# Failed to install dbus-python

Tags: python, pip, dbus, python-wheel

I was up to build a notifier program by python. I used notify2 library, bbut when it is to run the " import notify2" an error occured that can't import dbus library inside the notify2 main code source.

this is the error shown on the terminal:

```
import notify2
  File "C:\....\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\notify2.py", line 39, in <module>
    import dbus
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
```

When I tried to install dbus doing so "pip install dbus-python", it couldn't run because of unknown isuue kind of related to "wheels"..!

this is part of the error raised:

```
   Building wheel for patchelf (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [9 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Djamel.T\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-c4vjr2q6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\Djamel.T\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-c4vjr2q6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\Djamel.T\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-c4vjr2q6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
     
        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for patchelf
      Failed to build patchelf
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for patchelf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

If any who had similair experience, please guide me throught this problem..

I went through other solutions related to updating pip, installing wheels but the same error still raised...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbus+pip+python